# What are all of clojure's special forms?

Tags: clojure, symbols

As part of improving Cider's debugger, I need to implement special handling for all possible special-forms. In order words, I need to know all symbols which satisfy `special-symbol?`.
The doc page on [Special Forms](http://clojure.org/special_forms), while helpful, doesn't offer all of them.

For instance, after some experimentation, I've learned that

1. Most of the forms listed there have a `*` counterpart (`let*` and `loop*`, for instance).
2. There is a `clojure.core/import*` special-symbol (which I wouldn't have found if not for sheer luck).

Is there a complete list of all special symbols?
Alternatively, is there a way to list all interned symbols? If so, then I could filter over `special-symbol?`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looking at the definition of `special-symbol?` provides a big clue:

```
(defn special-symbol?
  "Returns true if s names a special form"
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  [s]
    (contains? (. clojure.lang.Compiler specials) s))
```

---

Thus:

```
user=> (pprint (keys (. clojure.lang.Compiler specials)))
(&
 monitor-exit
 case*
 try
 reify*
 finally
 loop*
 do
 letfn*
 if
 clojure.core/import*
 new
 deftype*
 let*
 fn*
 recur
 set!
 .
 var
 quote
 catch
 throw
 monitor-enter
 def)
```

Comment: Damn, now I'm embarassed. Forgot to Use The Source.